# No results for fingerprint search using the GNSDK (3.06) java wrapper - any recommended params?

Tags: java, audio, gracenote

I have a live stream of audio which i try to fingerprint & search using the GNSDK(3.06) java wrapper.
My code is based on the musicid_stream sample.

I use the code:

```
gnMusicID.fingerprintBegin(
GnFingerprintType.kFingerprintTypeGNFPX, 
44100, 
16, 
2
);

/* write audio to the finger printer */
gnMusicID.fingerprintWrite(audioData, audioData.length);

/* does the finger printer have enough audio? */
gnMusicID.fingerprintEnd();
```

where audioData is byte[] of the audio's PCM

I was looking for information in your API reference with params you recommend using:

- how long should the recording be? minimum seconds?
- should I try GnFingerprintType.kFingerprintTypeStream3 \ GnFingerprintType.kFingerprintTypeStream6 as the GnFingerprintType?
- use higher sampling rate?

My audio buffer might be at any position during the song as I record a live audio.

please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried them but none of them made the percentage of recognition any better (it is very low), and I am looking for some information that can't be found in the API reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the music stream was not clean and figured out how to get better stream...

FYI:
I currently use 6 seconds of recordings and the above params and get quite good results.